# Trying to swap nodes data

Tags: c

I'm trying to arrange the linked list data by name so I'm comparing each node name with the next one. and yes  want to swap nodes data, to have a linked list arranged by name.

I've tried to swap each data of node with the other in case the test in function "trier" is true the test is `(strcmp(prec, ptr) < 0)`. it seems working well until the last one.
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

struct patient {
    int cin;
    char nom[8];
    char prenom[8];
    int annee;
    struct patient *suivant;
};

struct patient *tete = NULL;

void creationdePatient() {
    struct patient* ptr;
    char rep;

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct patient));
    tete = ptr;
    printf("Saisir Numero de Cin de Nouveau Patient: ");
    scanf("%d", &tete->cin);
    printf("Saisir Nom de Patient: ");
    scanf("%8s", &tete->nom);
    printf("Saisir prenom de Patient: ");
    scanf("%8s", &tete->prenom);
    printf("Saisir annee de naissance de Patient: ");
    scanf("%d", &tete->annee);
    tete->suivant = NULL;
    printf("\nVoulez vous Saisir un autre Patient ?: (O,N): \n");
    scanf(" %c", &rep);

    while (toupper(rep) == 'O') {
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct patient));
        printf("Saisir Numero de Cin de Nouveau Patient: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->cin);
        printf("Saisir Nom de Patient: ");
        scanf("%8s", &ptr->nom);
        printf("Saisir prenom de Patient: ");
        scanf("%8s", &ptr->prenom);
        printf("Saisir annee de naissance de Patient: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->annee);
        ptr->suivant = tete;
        tete = ptr;
        printf("\nVoulez vous Saisir un autre Patient ?: (O,N): \n");
        scanf(" %c", &rep);
    }
}

void echangedeNom(struct patient *x, struct patient *y) {
    char temp[8];
    strcpy(temp, y->nom);
    strcpy(y->nom, x->nom);
    strcpy(x->nom, temp);
}

void echangedePrenom(struct patient *x, struct patient *y) {
    char temp[8];
    strcpy(temp, y->prenom);
    strcpy(y->prenom, x->prenom);
    strcpy(x->prenom, temp);
}

void echangedesentiers(struct patient *x, struct patient *y) {
    int temp = 0;
    temp = y->cin;
    y->cin = x->cin;
    x->cin = temp;
}

void echangedesannes(struct patient *x, struct patient *y) {
    int temp = 0;
    temp = y->annee;
    y->annee = x->annee;
    x->annee = temp;
}

void printtList() {
    struct patient *temp = tete;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Cin: %d | Nom:%s | Prenom: %s |Anne de naissance: %d\n",
               temp->cin, temp->nom, temp->prenom, temp->annee);
        temp = temp->suivant;
    }
}

void trier() {
    struct patient *ptr = tete;
    struct patient *prec = NULL;
    int echange;
    do {
        echange = 0;

        while (ptr != NULL && ptr->suivant != NULL) {
            prec = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->suivant;
            if (strcmp(prec->nom, ptr->nom) < 0) {
                echangedeNom(prec, ptr);
                echangedePrenom(prec, ptr);
                echangedesentiers(prec, ptr);
                echangedesannes(prec, ptr);
                echange = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (echange == 1);
}

int main() {
    creationdePatient();
    printtList();
    trier();
    printf("=======================\n");
    printtList();
}
```

some data while swapping get the wrong information like the `cin` number after swapping is not the same anymore.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%8s", &tete->prenom);`  1) The field: `prenom` is only 8 bytes long.  The input format specifier: `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input, so the "%8s"  can allow the input to overflow the input buffer.  Suggest `"%7s"`  2)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. Note: the returned value is a count of number of successful input conversions (or EOF)  Suggest: `if ( scanf("%7s", &tete->prenom) != 1) { // handle error }`  Similar considerations exist for the other calls to `scanf()`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%8s", &ptr->nom)`  in C, referencing an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array. `char * ptr->nom[8]`  results in the  compiler outputting:: `:27:14: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[8]’ [-Wformat=]`  Suggest: removing the leading '&'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are swapping twice an integer here:

```
while(ptr!=NULL && ptr->suivant!=NULL){
    // [...]
    echangedesentiers(prec,ptr);
    echangedesentiers(prec,ptr);
    // [...]
}
```

By the way, here is a first step to learn to debug your code : *[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)*.

Comment: i've edit it can u check the next issue, thanks btw.

Comment: @AyoubSouid, A better way is to learn to debug a the program you're writing. Also please check this page about the purpose of StackOverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic